# React setting default state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

Im looking for some guidance in terms of setting the default state in react.
I have a simple project using typescript & react that allows files to be dropped onto a div.
I'm trying to store these files in the state but I'm having trouble setting the default state.

```
export interface IAppState{
    value:string;
    droppedFiles: FileList
}
constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.state{
      value:'',
      droppedFiles?:???
    }
}

public render(): JSX.Element {
return (
  <div className="App">         
    <div className="Padding">
      <FileDrop onDrop={this.handleDrop}>
        Drop some files here!
      </FileDrop>
    </div>    
  </div>
);
}


private handleDrop = (files:FileList, event:ReactDragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
this.setState({
    droppedFiles:files
});
    console.log(this.state.droppedFiles);
}
```

If the droppedFiles is removed from the this.state step it obviously flags up as can't find the value. 
due to TypeScript's type safety, it won't accept {}. What's the proper way to initialize / set the default values for a complex type?

My main issue is that I'm faced with an error from typescript because I don't know how to initialize the state.droppedFiles property with the correct data. I don't want to assign any data to it in the constructor, I'll do that when the user actually drops files.
I'm just looking for the correct way to let TS know that the state has a property of 'droppedFiles' which is of type 'FileList':
[TS Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blOSh.png)

Without this part it throws an error at runtime which I would expect:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a0fj.png)

---

So to close it off, It turns out that FileList isn't a File[].
to get around this I updated my Interface:

```
export interface IAppState{    
    droppedFiles: File[];
}
```

I initialized it in my constructor like so:

```
constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      droppedFiles: []      
    }
}
```

and finally to update my state I extracted each item from the FileList:

```
private handleDrop = (files:FileList, event:ReactDragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {


    // Create an array from the FileList (as this is an array-like object)    
    const filesArr: File[] = Array.from(files);

        // Update the state with our new array
        this.setState({
          droppedFiles: filesArr
        });
      }
```

This has sorted my issue. Thanks for putting me on the right path estus. Kudos.

Comment: The question lacks necessary details. Should it really be FileList and not an array? If `droppedFiles ` is optional then mark it as optional.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The question isn't really about the validity of the code (apologies if it isn't up to par) its more about how you would set the default value of an item in state if the datatype of that item isn't a simple one (string, number, array, object) and is more complex (like defined in a custom interface) - FileList is just an example here as it relates to a current issue I have.

Comment: It depends on what the value is and how it's used. TS is structurally typed so it doesn't differentiate between 'complex' and 'simple' types. The question doesn't make sense in general. In one case you could make property optional and in another one you couldn't.

Comment: Updated Again. top man. thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question cannot be extrapolated to any case. In this specific case if initial value for a property cannot be provided, a property should be made optional:

```
export interface IAppState{
    value:string;
    droppedFiles?: FileList
}
```

And this implies that in places where `droppedFiles` is used it can be either `FileList` or `undefined`, it may require `if (this.state.droppedFiles) ...` checks, etc.

Another option in this specific case is to not use `FileList` object (which is array-like) and store an array of `File` objects instead:

```
export interface IAppState{
    value:string;
    droppedFiles: File[]
}

...

this.state = { droppedFiles: [], ... }

...

this.setState({ droppedFiles: Array.from(files) });
```

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the property to be optional in this case but my main query is what should be set in the setState operation.

using this.setState = {droppedFiles: []} 
throws error: Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type 'FileList'.
  Property 'item' is missing in type 'never[]'.

removing it from setState throws this at run time as it cant find it:
Cannot read property 'droppedFiles' of null

Comment: You can unset optional property with `setState({ droppedFiles: undefined })`. You should care in the first place not just how to type it properly but how values actually treated. If `droppedFiles` is not expected to be an array and assigning it to empty array will make code unworkable at runtime, that's wrong type. *removing it from setState* - how did you do that? You will get an error like *Cannot read property 'droppedFiles' of null* only if your code is messed up. `this.state` isn't expected to be null. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem.

Comment: I see. As I said, `{droppedFiles: []}` is incorrect, it's just wrong object that's incompatible with `FileList` object (at runtime). FWIW, I updated the answer with explanation what's the deal with an array that I suggested previously. And you didn't post the code that is responsible for `Cannot read property 'droppedFiles' of null` error. You will get it only if `this.state === null`, it can't be null under normal circumstances.